# Getting files ordered by date in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, storagefile

I am working on a windows phone 8.1(RT) based project where I want to display a list of files based on the date they were created. When I tried the code from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227254.aspx), I get a 'System.NotImplementedException'.

And also my intellisense suggest me that its not implemented in windows phone 8.1. So does that mean I cant use Query option or is there any alternatives?
Code:

```
StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;

// Get the files in the user's Pictures folder and sort them by date.
StorageFileQueryResult results =
picturesFolder.CreateFileQuery(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate);

// Iterate over the results and print the list of files
// to the Visual Studio Output window.
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> sortedFiles =
      await results.GetFilesAsync();
      foreach (StorageFile item in sortedFiles)
      {
          Debug.WriteLine(item.Name + ", " + item.DateCreated);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it throws the 'System.NotImplementedException' then it isn't available in your current target environment (kinda sucks, but you will find a few things they left out of the Windows.winmd, probably because of time constraints)

How ever, you can use the normal way of getting a list of files from a `StorageFolder`

```
StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync();
```

According to the documentation you can even pass your `OrderByDate` to it

```
StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate);
```

Or you can just sort the `IList<StorageFile>` yourself, it shouldn't be too hard.

[MSDN: StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery) | getFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/br227274.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried the suggested code but getting a 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' on the line StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate);

Comment: Okay I've tried something like                await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate);
 and it works great. But when I choose a specific folder inside PicturesLibrary and try using the same code it gives me a  'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'. Any clue how to get rid of this?

Comment: @AbsoluteSith Yeah you need to use `async` and  `await` calls for everything you do.  For  default folders, I think you need to make sure you have permissions setup correctly in the manifest.  As for the subfolder, I think you need to get the user to select the folder first, I'm pretty sure you can not directly access it.  Look up traversing a sub folders under windows phone, and try it in your local assets folder first, which you have total access to.